# Triggers are not copied when copying a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Triggers are lost when copying a Google spreadsheet. I tried on open but it wont work on the new copy. Is there any way to reactivate the triggers problematically?

```html
function onOpen() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
 
   //delete all previous triggers
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();
  // Loop over all triggers
  for(var i=0; i < allTriggers.length; i++)
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  
   // Create onopen trigger using the Spreadsheet
  var onEditTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("onOpen")
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
  
         // Create onedit trigger using the Spreadsheet

 var onEditTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEdit")
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the trigger through code, but it'll require at least a click on a menu (or image button) in order for it to work. Because it'll require a new authorization confirmation.

Also, you're mixing up the simple and installable triggers on the same function. Which is probably a mistake.

You should either using simple triggers, which are "set" just by naming the function  `onOpen` and `onEdit`. Or installable triggers, which you add on the triggers menu (or via code, as you're doing).

Well... you can have both, but it does not make sense to have both triggering the same function.